# what filter should I add to get the same transaction_date fields within last 14 or 15 days in Netsuite - suitescript?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am writing Netsuite Suitescript. I want to add in an attribute to my search as to find similar matching transaction dates within last 2 weeks. So i dont know what filter or attributes  to add in this line

```
column[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_sub_transaction_date', null, null);
```

I want to know how to add in that filter so that i get to search for 14 or 15 days of the same transaction_date instead of those null attributes in that line of code???

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
var filters = [];
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('custrecord_sub_transaction_date', null, 'onorafter', ['weekbeforelasttodate']));
```